# What is the Fourier series of $f(x)$

Tags: calculus, fourier-analysis, fourier-series

> What is Fourier series of $$f(x) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\cos nx}{2^n}$$

Now, it was claimed that since $f(x)$ converge uniformly and:

$$f(x) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{e^{inx} + e^{i(-n)x}}{2^{n+1}} = \sum_{n\ne 1} \frac{e^{inx}}{2^{|n|+1}}$$

Then **it must be** that the Fourier coefficients are exactly the coefficients of the series.

Why is that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Fourier coefficient of $f$ are defined as taking the inner product of $f$ with a basic trigonometric polynomial. Because the series converges uniformly the order of integration and summation may be exchanged. Thus:
$$<f,cos(nx)>=\int_{0}^{2\pi}f(x) \cos (nx)dx=\int_{0}^{2\pi}(\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}2^{-m}\cos(mx))\cos (nx)dx$$
$$=\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{2\pi}2^{-m}\cos(mx) \cos (nx)dx = \sum_{m=1}^\infty <2^{-m}\cos(mx),\cos(nx)>=2^{-n}\delta_{m,n}$$
A similar calculation shows that the coefficients of the sin functions are 0.

Comment: Thank you, but I'd like to understand why this claim is valid for every such $f$ represented by a series converges uniformly.

Comment: @Elimination: You need to be a little more precise: Which claim? A function which is defined as a trigonometric series and converges uniformly, has as its Fourier coefficients precisely the coefficients in the series. This is because when a sequence of functions converges uniformly you may interchange integration and the sequence limit, so you may emulate the argument above.

Comment: Thank you. I have tried it for the general case and now I understand it!!